# query for creating view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

This is my code:

```
create DATABASE assignment

CREATE TABLE Books (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    category TEXT,
    price FLOAT CHECK (price>0), 
    promoted bit DEFAULT 1
);

INSERT INTO Books (id, category, price) VALUES (1, 'Dictionary', 100); 
INSERT INTO Books (id, category, price) VALUES (2, 'Dictionary', 150); 
INSERT INTO Books (id, category, price) VALUES (3, 'Science', 120); 
INSERT INTO Books (id, category, price) VALUES (4, 'Science', 190); 
INSERT INTO Books  (id, category, price) VALUES (5, 'Science', 320);

CREATE VIEW PromotionSummary AS
SELECT category, MIN(price) AS minprice , MAX(price) AS maxprice 
FROM Books
WHERE promoted
GROUP BY category;
```

facing this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PromotionSummary, Line 5
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'.

I am using azure database right now.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server - use the correct engine reference!

Comment: The bit datatype can be used with the notation b'n'.  In your case, it would be WHERE promoted = b'1' for true.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html If you tried BOOLEAN it apparently automatically converts true and false to 1 and 0;  I'm more confident behind the boolean data type (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/) but I think both could work.  Everything else looks good.

Comment: Aside: SQL Server supports the [bit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.) There is a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL. If so, then you need to a value on the predicate on `promoted` (MySQL would allow that, but not SQL Server). Presumably, you want:

```
CREATE VIEW PromotionSummary AS 
SELECT category, MIN(price) AS minprice , MAX(price) AS maxprice 
FROM Books 
WHERE promoted = 1 
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: @tatemallies: just don't use datatype `text`. `nvarchar(...)` is better. `text` is an old datatype, that is planned for deprecation, as [explained in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @tatemallies: no, that's in the definition of your table. Column `category` should be defined as `varchar()` rather than `text`, like
`CREATE TABLE Books (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    category VARCHAR(50), 
    price FLOAT CHECK (price>0), 
    promoted bit DEFAULT 1
);
`

Comment: @GMB . . . `text` (and so on) are *already* deprecated.  That means they are planned for removal in the future.